# Mastermind in python input validation and tracking confusion

Tags: python, input

I'm having trouble with a program for class and need a little help. We have to make a mastermind program but it needs to list the number of guesses made, the changing right answer that is given by the user and a hint containing what the user has right and how many times they have it right in the answer they gave. At the end it needs to list the number of their guesses. Here is what I have so far and for some reason whenever i try to test it the whole thing locks up and i need to restart the kernal of canopy.

```
import random

def mastermind():
    print 'working'
    count= 1
    s_code = []
    total_colors_right = 0
    total_in_right_pos = 0
    allguess = []
    theseguess = ()
    while count <6:
        ran_choice = random.choice('ryobg')
        s_code.append(ran_choice)
        count = count+1
        s_code.append(ran_choice)
        print s_code
        print "lets play a game"
        print "I the great and almighty OZ have selected a list of five colors choose wisely and their will be no consequences"
        print
        print "For each turn i will ask you to choose five colors. There are no rules I can choose the same color as many times as i want and so can you"
        print "Have the clors match mine and you will win  i wil give the occasional hint ahd the secret list of colors will stay the same for the entire length of our match"
        print "I will keep track of your colors and how many times you guess"
        print "i dont know why but im feeling generous so you can have an unlimited amount of guesses"
        print "if your feeling competitive have someone compare their score to yours and come back soon"
        print "have a good time, and don't anger me you won't like me when I'm angry"
        print "oh and by the way please just type your answer in one letter I don't feel like reading a whole word"
        not_correct = True
        while not_correct:
            position = 0
        guess_ctr= []
        for position in range(0,5):
            guess = raw_input('make your guess here genius >>')
            guess_ctr.append(guess)
        print "You guessed:",guess_ctr
        these_guesses = guess_ctr[0],guess_ctr[1],guess_ctr[2],guess_ctr[3],guess_ctr[3]
        print "these guesses are ",theseguess
        allguess.append(these_guesses)
        print "all your guesses are: ",allguess
        print total_colors_right,total_in_right_pos

        print "total colors right ",total_colors_right,",total in right position" 
        if total_in_right_pos == 5:
            not_correct = False
        else:
            not_correct = True
            print allguess
            print "well, I think that you've won"
            print
            print "well we cant have that now can we"
            print "have fun in umm... the... uhhh"
            print "the magic garden yeah thats definately a real place yup, have fun!"
            print
            print
            print "you were evaporated into a puff of greasy smoke"
            print 'goodbye, chump, have fun in the trashcan with the last one'

    def compare_lists(colors,secret,guess):
            print"secret list is",secret
            print"your list is",guess
            secret_red = secret.count('r')
            secret_orange = secret.count('o')
            secret_yellow = secret.count('y')
            secret_green = secret.count('g')
            secret_blue= secret.count('b')
            player_red = guess.count('r')
            player_orange = guess.count('o')
            player_yellow = guess.count('y')
            player_green = guess.count('g')
            player_blue= guess.count('b')
            total_colors_right = min(secret_red,player_red) -\
            min(secret_orange,player_orange) +min(secret_yellow,player_yellow)+\
            min(secret_green,player_green)+min(secret_blue,player_blue)
            print 'Total colors right: ',total_colors_right
            return total_colors_right
```

Any and all help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: `        while not_correct: position = 0` is always going to be true since you dont change `not_currect` inside of the while loop. unless theres just an indent error which seems plausible

Answer (score 1):

R Nar nailed the immediate problem: you have a trivially infinite loop.  The problem is your indentation: you apparently intended the rest of the **mastermind** routine to be part of that loop.  Shove it over, like this:

```
    not_correct = True
    while not_correct:
        position = 0
        guess_ctr = []
        for position in range(0,5):
            guess = raw_input('make your guess here genius >>')
            guess_ctr.append(guess)
        print "You guessed:",guess_ctr
        these_guesses = guess_ctr[0],guess_ctr[1],guess_ctr[2],guess_ctr[3],guess_ctr[3]
        print "these guesses are ",theseguess
        allguess.append(these_guesses)
        print "all your guesses are: ",allguess
        print total_colors_right,total_in_right_pos

        print "total colors right ",total_colors_right,",total in right position"
        if total_in_right_pos == 5:
            not_correct = False
        else:
            not_correct = True
            print allguess
            print "well, I think that you've won"
            print
            print "well we cant have that now can we"
            print "have fun in umm... the... uhhh"
            print "the magic garden yeah thats definately a real place yup, have fun!"
            print
            print
            print "you were evaporated into a puff of greasy smoke"
            print 'goodbye, chump, have fun in the trashcan with the last one'
```

This brings up a frequent point in program development.  How did you get this much code written without noticing that your main gaming loop is infinite?

Write a few lines at a time.  Check their operation.  Insert print statements to track program flow and variable values.  When those statements work, *then* add more.  Without this incremental development, you often find yourself in exactly this position: two screens of new code, and no clues.

You will next notice that your end-of-game logic is reversed.  It might help to simplify your logic.  First of all, drop the **not_** in front of **correct**, so that your main loop reads

```
while not correct:
```

Note that you get the same effect here -- the Python negation operator is just what you wanted, anyway.  In your decision below, you now get

```
        if total_in_right_pos == 5:
            correct = True
        else:
            correct = False
            print allguess
            ...
```

Or, more directly (and now we can see the proper logic)

```
        correct = total_in_right_pos == 5:
        if correct:
            print allguess
            ...
```

There are many other improvements to make, not to mention a good proofreading of your game text.  However, I'll keep to brevity and the old adage:

First make it work.

Then make it work well.

Last, make it pretty.